# Why making gap UIWindow in top and bottom iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bitcode

Every thing was going fine but after updating xcode 6 to 7 there was an error in build. After changing "Enable bitcode" Yes to No in Build Option application built successfully. But I am facing a new problem -

Application screen size making gap top and bottom as following

[image]

I have added following line in method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but nothing done

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

**My application is XIB file based not StoryBoard.**

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your `LaunchScreen` in `Assets.xcassets` Like This :

[image]

I hope it's help for you.

Comment: For OP, How did it worked with iOS 8 also without this?